# Qt Creator, работа с кнопками

Tags: c++, qt

Хотел бы узнать, если я создал кнопку не через графический интерфейс, а обычно прописав ее:

```
QPushButton *ledButton = new QPushButton("LED Button");
layout->addWidget(ledButton);
```

как к ней, подключить такой код?

```
void MainWindow::on_ledButton_clicked()
{

}
```

Comment: через сигналы и слоты

Comment: @Akuma925 могли бы Вы предоставить подробный пример?

Comment: вот тут развернутый пример https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_QPushButton/ru

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код подключения

```
connect (ledButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_ledButton_clicked()));
```

Comment: При этом метод on_ledButton_clicked должен быть объявлен как public slots